# mysql.gtid_executed table is empty

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I want to keep track of GTIDs and the corresponding mysqlbin log somewhere. I see this mysql.gtid_executed table, however on my mariadb DB, there are no rows in this table. Any idea how this gets populated ? These are the GTID related parameters. Any help is appreciated.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show variables like '%gtid%';
+-------------------------+--------------+
| Variable_name           | Value        |
+-------------------------+--------------+
| gtid_binlog_pos         | 0-10001-4866 |
| gtid_binlog_state       | 0-10001-4866 |
| gtid_cleanup_batch_size | 64           |
| gtid_current_pos        | 0-10001-4866 |
| gtid_domain_id          | 0            |
| gtid_ignore_duplicates  | OFF          |
| gtid_pos_auto_engines   |              |
| gtid_seq_no             | 0            |
| gtid_slave_pos          | 0-10001-4866 |
| gtid_strict_mode        | ON           |
| last_gtid               |              |
| wsrep_gtid_domain_id    | 0            |
| wsrep_gtid_mode         | OFF          |
| wsrep_gtid_seq_no       | 0            |
+-------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'keep track of'. For what purpose? What problem are you solving?

Comment: I have a GTID say 1-10001-6754 that caused an errant transaction few days back, I didn't notice it then. The mysqlbinlogs and relay logs are purged and no more. I want to restore those logs onto server but I don't know which binlog/relay log they belong to.

Comment: So I have this info somewhere - "GTID, binlog, date created" it makes my life easier when it comes to restoring that exact binlog.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, I've searched though the [outstanding issues](https://jira.mariadb.org) and have found no task that resembles this. I encourage you to request it. MariaDB needs to solve a user's problems and its the reporting of these troubles that leads to it becoming a better product.

Answer (score 0):

`gtid_executed` table is from your former MySQL instance. It isn't used by MariaDB.

The global `gtid%pos` variables you have listed keep track of the gtid.